# ECMAScript 6 support in PhpStorm 2016

Tags: ecmascript-6, phpstorm

I recently pulled in the latest Laravel 5.3. In the `gulp.js` file, there is the newer ES6 arrow function syntax:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

PhpStorm 2016.2 shows this code error on that:

```
Expression statement is not assignment or call.
```

Additionally, the code auto-formatter mucks everything up when it encounters this because it sees it as an error.

How do I get PhpStorm to stop showing that as an error?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Go to `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript`

Then change `JavaScript language version` to `ECMAScript 6`

Comment: Is there any way to make ECMAScript6 the default language version? I can only seem to be able to set it per project.

Comment: @Gustavo: Go to `File > Default Settings...` then `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript`. Change there `JavaScript Language Version` to `ECMAScript 6`

Answer (score 4):

**MacOs**: `Menu > PhpStorm> Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript` and change `JavaScript language version to ECMAScript 6`